# Getting error for variable does not exist in current context cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have following code for getting error

```
$('#Template').click(function () {
            var selectedTempleteType = $('#BulkLoadActionDropDownId option:selected').val();
            var path = '@Url.Content("~/Upload/DownloadBulkLoadActionTemplate?templateType=" + selectedTempleteType)';
            $(this).attr("href", path);
        });
```

error showing for "selectedTempleteType".

Comment: `@Url.Content` is razor (server side) code - its executed on the server before the html is sent to the client. `selectedTempleteType` is a javascript (client side) variable - its does not exist on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedTempleteType` is a client-side JS variable, you cannot use it inside `@Url.Content()` which runs server-side (and `@Url.Content()` is incorrect to map URL path with query string, use `@Url.Action()` instead). You should change from this:

```
var path = '@Url.Content("~/Upload/DownloadBulkLoadActionTemplate?templateType=" + selectedTempleteType)';
```

to this one:

```
var path = '@Url.Action("DownloadBulkLoadActionTemplate", "Upload")?templateType=' + selectedTempleteType;
```

Or using placeholder inside `@Url.Action()` with `replace()` in client-side:

```
var path = '@Url.Action("DownloadBulkLoadActionTemplate", "Upload", new { templateType = "xxxx" })';
path = path.replace("xxxx", selectedTempleteType);
```